# Working with JS objects in IE9

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-5

I've looked far and wide and the solutions on SO don't work for me.
How can I rewrite:

```
for(const key of Object.keys(objRules)) {}
```

into IE9 (ES5) compatible code?

My JS obj looks like:

```
{
  0: {name: "Text1", fillBy: "name@email.com", mandatory: true},
  1: {name: "Group1", fillBy: "name@email.com", mandatory: true}
}
```

Comment: Maybe jQuery's `$.each()`?

Comment: `for( key in objRules)`...

Comment: according to MDN, `Object.keys()` is available in IE9, so it's only about the `for of` loop. `Object.keys(objRules).forEach(function(key){ ... })` Besides that, check out [polyfill.io](//polyfill.io)

Comment: Uh, it looks like that object really should be an array.

Comment: Thanks guys! see answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wan't to loop trough your objects?

Just use normal for loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    var name = obj[i].name;
    var fillby = obj[i].fillBy;
    var mandatory = obj[i].mandatory;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this doesn't iterate over inherited prototypal properties as well?

Comment: I think so. But the best would be to just try it out =)

Comment: Thanks! I'm marking this as right. Worked perfectly! the other way to do it is with 2 ugly loops: for( key in obj) {
            for(key2 in obj[key]) {
  
            }
          }